# SecurityManager policies - any way to escalate privileges?

Tags: java, security

I have just read an article about sandboxes based on java SecurityManager with custom policies ([Self-Protecting Sandbox using SecurityManager](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/12/29/sandbox-experiment/)) and can't explain to myself how out of 7 listed permissions that make up a defenseless sandbox one could exploit these 3:

- RuntimePermission("createClassLoader")
- RuntimePermission("accessClassInPackage.sun")
- ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")

I'm going to run (highly) untrusted code in my service and I definitely need above permissions to get things working correctly. The question is, having these 3 policies granted what consequences should I expect? Is there any way to load a code (as we have "createClassLoader" granted) which will escape SecurityManager control?

Comment: Is it *your* code that needs those permissions to function correctly, or the untrusted?

Comment: This is unfortunately my code. I'm simply trying to evaluate 3rd party (untrusted) code via provided (and trusted) tool which needs these 3 permissions to run.

Comment: It's not unfortunate at all -- the other way around would indeed be unfortunate. :) All you have to do is assign the permissions to your trusted code base only, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html). As for why those permissions you mention can be considered sandbox-defeating, just take a look at their respective javadocs.

Comment: Indeed, everything I needed was described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimePermission.html